# NTFS Special permissions - List Folder/Read Data and Read Attributes

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions

I applied ntfs special permission "List Folder/Read Data" on a folder that contains a simple text file, now i can open the folder and see the names of files and subdirectories inside the folder , but i can't open the file to read its data , and when i do i get access denied ! , why is that ?

as far as i know:

> List Folder allows or denies viewing file names and subfolder names
> within the folder. List Folder affects the contents of that folder
> only and does not affect whether the folder you are setting the
> permission on will be listed. (Applies to folders only.)
>
> Read Data allows or denies viewing data in files. (Applies to files
> only.)

so Read Data part of the permission should allow me to read the content of the text file inside the folder.

another thing , weather i set the "Read Attributes" permission or not i still can see the file/folder standard attributes , it is like it has no effect at all !

Can anyone please guide me through this ?

Regards

Comment: Did you grant the permission as inheritable? Does it show up on the file as "inherited"?

Comment: @u1686_grawity yes , it show up in the subfolder and files

Comment: Please add the output of `icacls path\to\folder` and `icacls path\to\file` within a code box